# Emojis In string options

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am creating a color category menu and I just want to add custom color emojis like that <:aquaemoji:1083066333341687838> but it doesn't show as emoji [options photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cby6t.png)

```js
.addStringOption((option) =>
  option
    .setName("color-category")
    .setDescription("The qrcode color category")
    .addChoices(
      { name: "Blue", value: "#00F" },
      { name: "Cyan <:aquaemoji:1083066333341687838> ", value: "#00ACC6" },
      { name: "Green", value: "#00D207" },
      { name: "Gray", value: "#7F7F7F" },
      { name: "Orange", value: "#FF5B00" },
      { name: "Pink", value: "#FF00B3" },
      { name: "Purple", value: "#AB00DF" },
      { name: "Red", value: "#F00" },
      { name: "White", value: "#FFF" },
      { name: "Yellow", value: "#FF0" }
    )
);
```

Comment: You can't use emojis in choice names.